# Is there a 3rd party library for Android Pinch Zoom

Tags: android, zooming, multi-touch, touchscreen

Does anybody know whether there's a 3rd paty (or built in) library that helps in detecting and handling a pinch zoom event?

Basically what I'm looking for is some class that takes coordinates from a touch event and returns whether its a pinch zoom event or not...

Comment: Not a 3rd party lib but... have you looked at [this article](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847)?

Comment: @uTubeFan That's a nice article. The whole series.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this one: http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/

Not a lot of activity there, but you can take a look a the code.

this question should help you also: [Is there a built in API for handling pinch-zoom functionality in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645648/is-there-a-built-in-api-for-handling-pinch-zoom-functionality-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

The Android Developers Blog post at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html explains general handling of multitouch events and also gives examples of [ScaleGestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html), a component of the Android framework that detects pinch zoom gestures and calls back into your code to process it.

Comment: This looks great. I am gonna try that tonight. The only drawback is it is only supported by API Level 8+ which is a very limited market.

Comment: Not as limited as you might think: http://d.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html But if compatibility with older devices is critical, ScaleGestureDetector itself is open source like the rest of the core platform. You can get it from AOSP here: http://goo.gl/sOhqt change the package name, and bundle it in your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I will try that and let you know the results.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should have a look at this Library on Github https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom

Answer (score 0):

Is this help? It may be a little more simple than you thought:
[Implementing the Pinch Zoom Gesture](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847)