# android pinch-zoom in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Is pinch zoom functionality in Google map is possible, i have made several search but didn't get any solution, please give your view.

Or need to write the api for implementing these functionality.

Comment: Are you referring to MapActivity? in the Maps Library?

Comment: pinch zoom is available by default for 2.2 and above

Comment: @ Rajdeep Dua, yes I am referring to Map-activity.

Comment: u should probably check the answers here: [similar question]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645648/is-there-a-built-in-api-for-handling-pinch-zoom-functionality-in-android

Comment: sure I will have look into the content's... and thank's.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using ScaleGestureDetector to achieve Pinch and Zoom?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html

Refer to this blog post on how to leverage multi touch in Android

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Comment: Not implemented it, but should not be very difficult.Check Maps Application