# Can anyone point me to a detailed tutorial on multitouch in android?

Tags: android, touch, multi-touch

I can't seem to find anything and I have been looking hard for days. I can find gesture samples but no multitouch! I am able to the pointer count, but I have no idea where to go from there. In my app I am try to get it so that I can spin an object and it needs to be based off of 2 touch points.  Is there anyone out there that can point me to this?

Thanks

Comment: You can get started with this stackoverflow question. It has some code examples as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645648/is-there-a-built-in-api-for-handling-pinch-zoom-functionality-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial:

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/multitouch-and-gesture-detection-part-1

Hope that helps!